# Linux shutdown/reboot notification before network down

Tags: python, linux, shutdown, reboot

Is it possible to detect system shutdown/reboot in Linux before all network interfaces will be stopped? I can handle SIGTERM signal and check runlevel, but at this moment network maybe is down already. I need with functionality in my Python script.

Answer (score 1):

On shutdown (runlevel 0) or reboot (runlevel 6), the scripts in `/etc/rc.d/rc0.d/` or `/etc/rc.d/rc6.d/` respectively are run in order.  If you look in these dirs you will see stuff like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Feb 10  2012 K00ipmievd -> ../init.d/ipmievd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 16 Feb 25  2013 K01smartd -> ../init.d/smartd
 ...
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Dec 16 13:27 K90network -> ../init.d/network
 ...
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 14 Jul 27  2015 K95rdma -> ../init.d/rdma
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 18 Jul 27  2015 K99cpuspeed -> ../init.d/cpuspeed
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Dec 16 13:28 K99lvm2-monitor -> ../init.d/lvm2-monitor
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 14 Dec  8  2011 K99rngd -> ../init.d/rngd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Oct 24  2014 K99sysstat -> ../init.d/sysstat
```

If you want your shutdown script to run ahead of network shutdown, put it ahead of that.

You probably don't want to manipulate these directories directly, so see `man chkconfig`.

## EDIT

I should add that if your Linux is new enough to have `systemd` all of this is out the window.

Comment: Any idea on how to handle this with `systemd`?

Comment: As I loathe systems with the Fire of a thousand suns I haven't bothered to figure that out, sorry.